# How to use completions when prefixing a command with bundle exec?

Tags: ruby, fish

When I try to run a command like cap with `bundle exec cap` my completions for cap tasks do not work. Instead I get a directory listing:

```
> bundle exec cap -T
app/             config.ru  Gemfile.lock  package-lock.json  reference/             yarn.lock
babel.config.js  config/    Guardfile     postcss.config.js  spec/
bin/             db/        lib/          public/            ted_app_meta_data.yml
build/           doc/       log/          Rakefile           tmp/
Capfile          Gemfile    package.json  README.md          vendor/
```

```
> cap -T 
airbrake:deploy                         (Capistrano task)  deploy:finishing_rollback        (Capistrano task)  deploy:updating                                                                 (Capistrano task)  git:ini-1.3.8                    (Capistrano task)  unicorn:graceful_restart                 (Capistrano task)
```

It seems like fish can distinguish prefixing a command with `sudo`

```
> sudo cap
airbrake:deploy                         (Capistrano task)  deploy:finishing_rollback
```

So my question is, how do I get the behavior of `bundle exec` to mirror `sudo` for the purpose of summoning completions with Tab?

Comment: Next time you paste from your terminal, strip out your prompt: I can't see the command without scrolling horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how [sudo does it here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/4ffcbe35261c11cff032ee2689749ee08a39d3b9/share/completions/sudo.fish#L62). It adds a completion which strips `sudo` and sudo-specific options from the command line, and then reinvokes `complete -C` to generate completions for this subcommand.

One way to get this working with `bundle` would be:

1. Start with that `sudo.fish` file, copying it into `~/.config/fish/completions/bundle.fish`.
2. Edit that file to replace references to `sudo` with `bundle`.
3. Remove sudo-specific arguments and add any you want for bundle.

The sudo.fish file is probably already installed at `/usr/local/share/fish/completions/sudo.fish` or you may download it from GitHub.

The docs on [writing your own completions](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/completions.html) are a good reference.